# Making request with & (amp)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, jquery

I am trying to make a request using jQuery ajax, that contains `&`, where url:

```
var fileName = 'test&.pdf';
var resultUrl = url + encodeURIComponent(fileName);
```

So, the result url is `/Download/cbe1952c-1b16-40bc-9f93-7a801e0e68b8/true/test%2526.pdf`. But I retrieve server error `HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request`.
Any ideas?
**EDIT:**
I've found, that `%2526` is a result of double escaping of amp, so, jQuery ajax escapes it by itself. The new problem is the server says about the *potentially dangerous request*, when url contains `%26`.

Comment: You'll want to post the new problem as a separate question (and probably post your edit as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `encodeURIComponent`

```
var fileName = 'test&.pdf';
var resultUrl = url + encodeURIComponent(fileName);
```

The result will be `/Download/cbe1952c-1b16-40bc-9f93-7a801e0e68b8/true/test%26.pdf`

Comment: For documentation see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: as you say, your url should not encoded twice. I think if url encoded only once, server would not generate any warning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should just be %26.

```
/Download/cbe1952c-1b16-40bc-9f93-7a801e0e68b8/true/test%26.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

That is the wrong escape charater from an amp. Try `escape(fileName)` instead.

As in `"&" == "%26"` not `%2526`

Comment: *"Try `escape(fileName)` instead"* No. `escape` is not for URI-encoding. The OP is using the correct function.